# UI does not update when navigate to a screen in different stack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a situation as below

I have a tab navigator with stack navigators for each tabs. For example,

[image]

```
const AppContainer = createStackNavigator();

<AppContainer.Navigator
  initialRouteName="BottomTabScreens"
  screenOptions={{
    gestureEnabled: true,
    headerShown: false,
    ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS,
  }}
>
  <AppContainer.Screen
    name="BottomTabScreens"
    component={BottomTabScreens}
  />
  {...some other routes}
</AppContainer.Navigator>
```

Then inside the `BottomTabScreens.tsx` I have,

```
<Tab.Navigator
  initialRouteName="A"
  screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
      const { name } = route;
      return (
        <Image source={TabIcons(focused, name)} style={TabStyles.tabIcon} />
      );
    },
    // some style props
  })}
>
  <Tab.Screen
    name="A"
    component={B}
    options={{ headerShown: false }}
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="B"
    component={BStack} <-----------------------------------Notice here
    options={{ headerShown: false }
  />
  <Tab.Screen
    name="C"
    component={CStack}
  />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Now inside the `BStack.tsx` I have,

```
   <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="B1">
    <Stack.Screen
      name="B1"
      component={BSubScreen1} <------------ This is the middle UI of the above prototype 
      options={{ headerShown: false }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name="B2"
      component={BSubScreen2} <------------ This is the last UI of the above prototype
      options={headerOptions}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
```

Then I tried to navigate from Stack C to the nested screen of the Stack B ( BScreen2 ).

```
navigation.navigate("B2")
```

When I do this from a nested screen of a stack c, I get below error,

> The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload
> {"name":"B2","params":{"slug":"slug-id-1"}} was not handled by any
> navigator.
>
> Do you have a screen named 'B2'?
>
> If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see
> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.

So I have changed the navigation command as below,

```
navigation.navigate("B", {
 screen: "B1",
 params: {
   slug: 'slug-id-1'
 }
})
```

This works but the issue is, If i navigate back to the Stack C and try to go B1 with different param it does not re render the UI of B1 screen. But in the console, i can clearly see the API gets the new data for the new slug.

Also with the above navigation command, the B1 screen does not shows the back button, too

What am I doing wrong here ?

> Note - I replaced the component names ( B1, B2 ) for simplify the
> description

The content of the B2 screen

```
export const B2: React.FC<BasicNavigation> = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const {
        params: { slug }
      } = route;
      const { name } = await getPeopleMeta(slug);
      const { data } = await getPeopleBooks(slug);

      setName(name.toUpperCase());

      const filterredBooks = data.map(({ image, slug, title }) => {
        return { uri: posterSelector(image), slug, title };
      });
      setData(filterredBooks);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      // TODO: Display Error page
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const onPress = () => {
    throw new Error("Not Implemented");
  };

  const onAlltrialerBtnPress = () => {
    navigation.goBack();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <Spinner />;
  }

  return (
    <ScrollView style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
      <NameSection title={name} />
      <GridComponent items={data} onPress={onPress} />
      <GreyButton
        text="SEE ALL NEW"
        disable={false}
        onPress={onAlltrialerBtnPress}
      />
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you show some of your code to update the UI in B1 screen?

Comment: @gwl002 Thanks for the comment. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the B2 UI is not updated is that when going back from the C stack. The component will not mount again. The useEffect without deps will not call again. So there is two way to solve your problem.

1. add dep in the useEffect

```
const fetchData = async (slug) => {
    try {
      const { name } = await getPeopleMeta(slug);
      const { data } = await getPeopleBooks(slug);

      setName(name.toUpperCase());

      const filterredBooks = data.map(({ image, slug, title }) => {
        return { uri: posterSelector(image), slug, title };
      });
      setData(filterredBooks);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      // TODO: Display Error page
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetchData(route.params?.slug);
  }, [route.params?.slug]);
```

2. use [the useFocusEffect hooks](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but I can see in the console that HTTP request are getting called.

Comment: I'll try the `useFocusEffect` and let know if it work

Comment: It's not normal. If you see the http request , how is the loading ?

Comment: Nothing change on the UI. Not even the loading spinner. I removed the route configuration of the B2 screen and added to the top level of the application and just used `navigator.navigate("B2")`. Then it start to work without an issue

Comment: No loading means fetchData is not called!

Answer (score 0):

If you can see that you are getting data from your API when you focus back to B1 it means that maybe you are rendering a flatlist that isn't being re-rendered when the new data comes. You can use the prop [extraData](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#extradata) to re-render a flatlist.

B1 Screen won't show the back button by default as it's the starting screen of B stack.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't have a FlatList in the component. It is just a basic component with a ScrollView